# Konva with stage draggable passing mouse events to layers

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

using konva's library I'm trying to be able to drag the whole stage only with the middle click which i've solutioned using:

```
this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
 container: canvasElement.id,
 width: this.initialWidth,
 height: this.initialHeight,
 scaleX: this.initialScale,
 scaleY: this.initialScale,
 draggable: true
});

let lastX = this.stage.position().x;
let lastY = this.stage.position().y;
this.stage.on('dragmove', (e) => {
 if (e.evt.buttons === 1) {
  this.stage.x(lastX);
  this.stage.y(lastY);
 } else {
  lastX = this.stage.position().x;
  lastY = this.stage.position().y;
 }
});
```

And now i wish to use the different mouse events on a specific layer in that stage while left click (which triggers the drag from the stage).

- mouseover
- mousedown
- mouseup
- mouseleave
- mouseenter
- contextmenu

But while the **canvas** is in dragging mode (even tho I've restricted the movement), it won't pass any event to childs.

Example of layer event handler:

```
this.layerGrid.on('mouseover', (e) => {
 const coords = new Coords(e.target.attrs.coords.x, e.target.attrs.coords.y);
 this.onMouseOver(coords);
});
```

I've tried to search for a way to only configure the draggable to be triggered only by middle click and ignore right click, without success, only found my actual way of restricting the movements directly.

I've also found a way handling manually the dragging with `onmousemove` and changing the stage position, but is there really no simple way using the builtin draggable for my case?

Comment: Layer (and Group) is not draggable by click-drag on empty space. Stage IS draggable by click-drag on empty space so you can be forgiven for assuming Layer would be the same. To drag a layer you need to click-drag a shape on the layer that has draggable = false.

Comment: Maybe my question as not clear enough @VanquishedWombat, I wish to keep the stage to be draggable, and I don't want the layers underneath to be, as listed in my question the only actions that I care to handle on the layer are mouseover, up, down, leave, enter, which are not being triggered if i'm in process of dragging the stage, even if i cancel the movement of that one (so it only drags with middle click, not left click)